# Функция removeSmallest(arr)

Tags: javascript

Дается массив с числами. Из них удаляется самый меньший и возвращается оставшийся массив. Если массив пустой или он не массив, то возвращается пустой массив. Исходный массив нельзя менять.
Функция removeSmallest(arr):

```
function removeSmallest(arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0 || Array.isArray(arr)) {
            var newArray = arr.slice();
            var index = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] >= arr[index]) {
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            delete newArray[index];
            return newArray;
        } else 
            return [];
}
```

Видимо проблема заключается тут:

```
if (arr[i] >= arr[index]) {
    index = i;
}
```

Comment: if (i >= arr[index]) {
                    index = i;
                } попробуйте так

Comment: Не получается никак

Comment: А что за проблема-то? Пока видно неверное направление сравнения, и неверное удаление элемента

Comment: А что делать, если минимальных элементов несколько?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Дается массив с числами. Из них удаляется самый меньший и возвращается оставшийся массив. Если массив пустой или он не массив, то возвращается пустой массив. Исходный массив нельзя менять.

```js
function removeSmallest(arr) {
// Если не пустой или массив, то идёт обработка
  if (arr.length !== 0 && Array.isArray(arr)) {
    // Находит минимум
    var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
    // Удалит минимульный элемент
    arr.splice(ar.indexOf(min), 1)
    return arr;
  } else
    return [];
}
var ar = [2, 3,-1, 4, 5, 8] // -1
console.info(removeSmallest(ar));
console.info(removeSmallest(''));
console.info(removeSmallest([]));
console.log(removeSmallest('fff'));
```

Comment: какой элемент из `[2, 3, 4, 5, 8]` будет `smallest`?

Comment: @Grundy благодарю, исправил.

Comment: Добавь пояснения к коду

Comment: @Grundy уже добавил :)

Comment: arr.splice(ar.indexOf(min), 1)
Ничего не замечаете?

Comment: var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
И здесь вместо null должен Math

Comment: @wan140, _может быть Math_ и _должен быть Math_ - Разные вещи. И тут он действительно может быть. Так как функция статическая и внутри себя `this` не использует можно передавать что угодно.